# Ошибка в движке

Tags: php

`Index.php`:

```
<?php
include('core.php');
$page = $_GET['page'];
switch($page){
  default:
  case '':
  $text = '';
  braek;  
}
include ('style/main.php');
include ('style/register.php');
?>
```

Ошибка в том, что когда открываешь `main.php` или `register.php`, то эти страницы сливаются в одну.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include('core.php');
$page = $_GET['page'];
switch($page){
  default:
  case '':
     include ('style/main.php');
  break;  
   case 'register':
     include ('style/register.php');
  break;

}
?>
```

Comment: АгА вот теперь я понял )))

Comment: Кстати отпечатка  была еще в break =)

Answer (score 0):

UPD

```
<?
include('core.php');
$page = $_GET['page'];
if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    switch($page) {
       case 'main.php' :
           include_once 'style/main.php';
       //кстати непонятно почему папка называется style?O_o
       break;

       case: 'register.php':
           include_once 'style/reigster.php';
       break;
    }
}
else {
    include_once 'style/main.php'; 
}
?>
```

если правильно понял то как-то так... Вообще почитали бы вы о построении структуры сайта ...
Ато на switch'e как то стремно выглядит %)

код написан правльно, если у вас все-равно что-то не работает то проблема не здесь...

Comment: меня слово нравиться =)

Comment: ну лично у меня сразу идет ассоциация с <b>css..</b>

Comment: )))Не чето не пашет ='( Ша попробую найти ошибку =)